# JQuery Scrollable Locking up after dynamic update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollable, jquery-scrollable

So I've been playing around with a JQuery plugin called [Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/). I'm impressed with how easy it was to get up and going, but now I've run into a show stopper and hope you guys can help.

My scrollable div contains a bunch of icons that are "featured" in a certain category. If the category is changed, I use JQuery to clear out the "featured items" div, calculate the number of items, and fill it in as necessary. I clear everything out because in the case there is 0 I don't write anything to the div and the content on my page adjusts.

My problem has been that after one of these clear out the scrolling stops working. I've tried calling

```
$("#scroller").scrollable({
    circular: false
});
```

after every update but that doesn't seem to fix the issue. I'm familiar with other JQuery tools using a "refresh" type command that reloads the content. Is there something similar with this plugin? Any ideas on what I should be doing instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try unbinding the scrollable object and re-binding after doing the DOM manipulation?

Comment: I've tried doing a "$("#scroller").unbind('scroll');
" at the beginning of each DOM manipulation, then a "$("#scroller").scrollable..." at the end of each. Is that what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rewriting the page to never remove the scollable div from the DOM. With that, I ended up using this workflow...

Scroll to the first item. If the user was on page 5 and what they select only has 3 pages, the user is stranded on a blank page if you don't scroll back.
`window.api.seekTo(0, 0);`
Empty the "items" div.
`$(".items").empty();`
Use the "addItem" method to add my items back in.
`window.api.addItem(htmlToAdd);`

That seemed to work much better.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function on Scrollable, `Scrollable.addItem` which should allow you to dynamically add items.